# How to add a text beside the total price calculation?

Tags: php, html

When you choose your quantity .. and you click on the distributor buttons u get message with the total price .. but it's only number .. can I add text beside it appears in this message?
Like 21 Dollars or $ or anything like that?
or can I make this total price appears in a text under the table without buttons?
( describe what do I do in details .. I've no PHP background and I didn't write any of these codes .. just wanna add the word beside the price number message

http://jsfiddle.net/HcPYM/

I use the jquery:

```
eval( $( 'td:nth-child(3)' ).map( function( td, $this ){
    return ( ( parseFloat( ( $this = $( this ) ).text() ) || 0 )
        * ( parseFloat( $this.parent().find( 'select' ).val() ) || 0 ) );
} ).get().join( '+' ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
eval('(' + $(..your map on your objects returning an array of string...).get().join('+') + ') + "$"')
```

in order to run:

```
eval('(3+4+5+6) + "$"')
```

But, as advice: avoid using `eval` which is bad for performance.

So, Here is a working example using simply jQuery and avoiding any evaluation :

[example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WZtQ/1/)  (As Michael Irigoyen insist.. :p)

Comment: Did you just tell the OP to avoid `eval` and then give him an answer using it? If they shouldn't use `eval`, provide a better solution.

Comment: I answer the question as it is the principle of the site. Moreover, I add an advice but it is just an advice.

Comment: again guys I have no background at all about php . so give me something to write instead of instructing me please :) thank you in advance

Comment: I give you a working example and/or a solution for your eval. Note that this is not a PHP problem as it concern only HTML and Javascript (jQuery)

Comment: yes i've tried it .. but I don't see any text next to the number still

Comment: can you give me your email to be in contact better than this way ?

Comment: ah ah I see now the link .. let me try

Comment: I can't do it dude .. it's working in your example but I don't know what to do to get it working in mine

Comment: mathieufab@gmail.com send me your PHP and JS file